# Magento - Customising the Newsletter Subscription

Tags: php, magento

We store our Newsletter Subscribers in a seperate database to Magento, and therefore when users sign up for an account we need to add their address to this database.

The code is located here:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php
```

And the relevant function (I think) is subscribeCustomer.

If I insert my code into the top of this function, it adds the users email address to the seperate database which is great.  However it does this regardless of whether or not the "Subscribe to newsletter" box has been ticked.

I'm quite new to PHP so struggling to figure out where the code looks at the checkbox.  Is it somewhere in this function?

```
public function subscribeCustomer($customer)
{

    $this->loadByCustomer($customer);

    if ($customer->getImportMode()) {
        $this->setImportMode(true);
    }

    if (!$customer->getIsSubscribed() && !$this->getId()) {
        // If subscription flag not set or customer is not a subscriber
        // and no subscribe below
        return $this;
    }

    if(!$this->getId()) {
        $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
    }

   /*
    * Logical mismatch between customer registration confirmation code and customer password confirmation
    */
   $confirmation = null;
   if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired() && ($customer->getConfirmation() != $customer->getPassword())) {
       $confirmation = $customer->getConfirmation();
   }

    $sendInformationEmail = false;
    if ($customer->hasIsSubscribed()) {
        $status = $customer->getIsSubscribed()
            ? (!is_null($confirmation) ? self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED : self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
            : self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED;
        /**
         * If subscription status has been changed then send email to the customer
         */
        if ($status != self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED && $status != $this->getStatus()) {
            $sendInformationEmail = true;
        }
    } elseif (($this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED) && (is_null($confirmation))) {
        $status = self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED;
        $sendInformationEmail = true;
    } else {
        $status = ($this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE ? self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED : $this->getStatus());
    }

    if($status != $this->getStatus()) {
        $this->setIsStatusChanged(true);
    }

    $this->setStatus($status);

    if(!$this->getId()) {
        $storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
        if ($customer->getStoreId() == 0) {
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getWebsite($customer->getWebsiteId())->getDefaultStore()->getId();
        }
        $this->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setEmail($customer->getEmail());
    } else {
        $this->setStoreId($customer->getStoreId())
            ->setEmail($customer->getEmail());
    }

    $this->save();
    $sendSubscription = $customer->getData('sendSubscription') || $sendInformationEmail;
    if (is_null($sendSubscription) xor $sendSubscription) {
        if ($this->getIsStatusChanged() && $status == self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED) {
            $this->sendUnsubscriptionEmail();
        } elseif ($this->getIsStatusChanged() && $status == self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED) {
            $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the event observers and avoid adding code to Magento's core.

Create a new module in `app/code/local` or `app/code/community` and add the following in it's `config.xml` under the `config > global > events` node.

```
<newsletter_subscriber_save_commit_after>
    <observers>
        <newsletter_subscriber_external_db>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>subscribeExternalDb</method>
        </newsletter_subscriber_external_db>
    </observers>
</newsletter_subscriber_save_commit_after>
```

Then in the observer class add the following method:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Add subscriber to external database
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function subscribeExternalDb(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber $subscriber */
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();

        // do whatever with subscriber model
    }
}
```